# why does this function give me a segmentation error when I the return type on a variable such as a char*?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

```
LWDL_string LWDL_getString(LWDL_Data data,LWDL_string list_name , LWDL_string value_name ){
  int ret , o = 0 , b = 0;
  LWDL_bool returned;
 for (o=0;o<data.lwdl_data_size  ;o++){
        if ((ret = strcmp(data.list_array.array[o].list_name,list_name)) == 0){
            
        for (b =0;b<data.list_array.array[o].list_values_name.used;b++){
                if ((ret = strcmp(data.list_array.array[o].list_values_name.array[b],value_name)) == 0){
                    returned = LWDL_true;
                    return data.list_array.array[o].list_values.array[b];
                }
        }

        }
    }
    if (returned == LWDL_false){
        printf("return didn't succeed.\nInfomation:\nlistname : %s\nvalue_name : %s", list_name,value_name);
        exit(-1);
    }
 }
```

LEGEND:

`LWDL_string = char*`

`LWDL_bool = int`

`LWDL_true = 1`

`LWDL_false = 0`

I have this function, but it gives me a segmentation error when I cast it on a variable such as a char*
the segment error is :
`line 9: 14818 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) ./a.out`

Comment: I don't understand your problem, but `returned` is potentially used uninitalized, which can cause your function to return without returning a value.

Comment: when I do something like `char* x =  LWDL_getString(data,"list" , "val");` 
I get a segmentation error for some reason. but, then when I use the function in a printf() it works. @1201ProgramAlarm

Comment: What is `LWDL_string` ? etc...

Comment: @wildplasser   LWDL_string = char*

LWDL_bool = int

LWDL_true = 1

LWDL_false = 0

Comment: Shouldn't you initialize returned? Have you tried to cast the result to char* before assignment?

Comment: I think so @HaibraynGonzález I have the code on github: https://github.com/lwdl/lwdl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return data.list_array.array[o].list_values.array[b];
```

Looks complicated. There is almost certainly something wrong with it. Oh and Haibrayn had a good point in that you don't set `returned` to anything when you declare it, so your `if` statement at the end of the function may not run and it would return to the caller with unset return values.

Use a debugger to ensure that bunch of data structures is what you assume it is. A debugger will also show you exactly where the program crashed.

If you're using Ubuntu as your user name suggests you can run the program with gdb at the command line. `gdb ./a.out` for example. Then you type `r` for run and let it rip. Good commands then are `info local` and `backtrace` or just `bt`.

If you had a program crash and it wasn't running under gdb, and you're on a systemd system like Ubuntu 18 or 20 look into the command line `coredumpctl` program.

I believe `coredumpctl debug` will launch the debugger on the last crashed program you have. There's lots more arguments to select particular crash dumps if you need them.

Comment: very helpful thanks!

Comment: hey dude you won't guess what the problem was. I was init the array for one of my arrays with the size of 1 as I used it to check what would happen. I spend a solid 2 hours wondering what was wrong (lol)